# How to pass authorization token header objective c?

Tags: objective-c, http-headers, authorization, nsurlrequest, ios9.1

I'm passing username,password for an API call it returns right value. But after authentication API returns an security token I need to capture the token and pass along with username and password.I'm doing the same but it returns forbidden error which denotes invalid token error.I also tried base64 to pass token as suggested at some answer in stackoverflow.The code I use to pass header values below

```
NSMutableURLRequest *request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
[request setHTTPMethod:[self HTTPMethod]];
[request setHTTPBody:self.requestData];
[request addValue:@"xyz" forHTTPHeaderField:@"username"];
[request addValue:@"xyz" forHTTPHeaderField:@"password"];
[request addValue:[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]valueForKey:@"Auth"] forHTTPHeaderField:@"Authorization"];
[request addValue:@"application/json" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
```

I searched for header methods, But nothing helps.what I'm doing wrong here.pls anybody help me fix it.Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use `setValue` for request instead of `addValue` because with `addValue` If a value was previously set for the specified field, the supplied value is appended to the existing value using the appropriate field delimiter

```
NSMutableURLRequest *request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
[request setHTTPMethod:[self HTTPMethod]];
[request setHTTPBody:self.requestData];
[request setValue:@"xyz" forHTTPHeaderField:@"username"];
[request setValue:@"xyz" forHTTPHeaderField:@"password"];
[request setValue:[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]valueForKey:@"Auth"] forHTTPHeaderField:@"Authorization"];
[request setValue:@"application/json" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
```

check apple documentation-

https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSMutableURLRequest_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSMutableURLRequest/setValue:forHTTPHeaderField

Comment: ,for the first time it returns correct value, but after all call returns error

Comment: It fixed by adding "/" at end of url